Why are Soviet leaders Gorbachev and Boris Yeltsin so loved in the west?
Why are Soviet leaders Gorbachev and Boris Yeltsin so popular in the west? And that they have so good relations with they west that the west are willing to work and form partnership with them What did they do different from previous soviet leadership that they were able to achieve this? Besides the obvious point that they brought down communism. Both are hailed as heros in the west.
I've look up Wikipedia and other online articles and they mentioned both men are hailed as heroes in the west but they never provide an in depth reason as to why that is the case. Side note I find Boris Yeltsin very funny with all his drunk videos on YouTube maybe that could give a clue why. Well for Mr I liked Yeltsin drunk and dancing videos. He's really hilarious.
https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=v9YnDirqwT4&t=26s&pp=2AEakAIB

I edited my post

Upvoted: Not many prior research, but I think the question is valid in itself

No evidence that Gorbachev and/or Yeltsin are loved in the west.

From my first-hand perspective living through it, they presided over the gradual (to eventually quite sudden) end of the Cold War. If you didn't grow up living under the constant threat of the world poised to be ending itself at any moment with not a damn thing you can do about it, you can't appreciate what it was like psychologically. Perhaps a bit like growing up in a house with two murderously violent parents who are constantly mad at each other. When one decides to ratchet things down a bit, and then later just allow both to stand down entirely, yeah you're happy with them.

Bringing the Cold War to an end might have something to do with it.  And, yes, the perception of Gorbachev especially is generally quite positive in the West.  Yeltsin maybe a little less so, as his later years showed him a bit erratic, but he was still one of the lead actors in opposing the 1993 coup.

Neither Gorbachev nor Yeltsin was or is 'loved' in the West?
Would you like to replace 'loved' with 'liked', or preferably 'respected'?
Both are acknowledged for their political views but neither 'acknowledged' nor 'respected' means anything like 'loved,'

These two people should not be considered as having the same relationship and notoriety in the West. Let's treat them separately.
Gorbachev:
When he reached supreme power in the USSR, Gorbachev started to have good relations with Margaret Thatcher, and she managed to introduce Ronald Reagan as well in the process.
This led to several agreements, including the diminution nuclear arsenals of both USA and USSR. Gorbachev acquired a posture of non-agressivity that was very softening the agressivity perceived by the West of his predecessors, because of the invasion of Afghanistan and others events. Also, Gorbachev was well perceived in United Kingdom because the country had powerful spies in the KGB: this helped in diminishing the misunderstanding of USSR by UK, and thus of Gorbachev.
Now, of course, comes the fall of USSR: Gorbachev was seen as somewhat who triggered that, even if the events, by far, were going without his will. The failed Coup d'Etat by military forces helped to strengthen his notoriety in the West as a liberty-led man fighting dark forces.
Yeltsin:
A different picture: the president of Russia at first politically fought Gorbachev, and won, which was a major step towards the break of USSR into several countries.
But after that, the picture of "Yeltsin the drunk man unable to govern Russia, a country where everything is sold to anybody, including weapons", which is a picture based on facts (Russian weapon trafficking in the 1990s, Yeltsin addiction to alcohol, the rising of private banks having bought public resources at low prices), was reaching the West, but was probably not well understood: At first, the "Russian rich self-made men" were seen as a good sign of economical liberty and rise in Russia, and not as the sign it is today of an oligarchy of corruption.
What eventually prevents Yeltsin to be perceived as the Russian perceived him is the rising of Putin and its "crusade" against the West: in contrast, under Yeltsin, Russia had no agressivity towards the West except for the criminal activities, that were not entirely the responsibility of the Russian state.
Let's conclude with Putin:
Putin:
From 2000 to 2008, Putin was not that blady seen in the West: he was reinforcing the authority of the state against groups of criminals, which was good news for the West. He was threatening when speaking of NATO, but this was not widely listened to in the West, only diplomats followed this sort of quotations, and probably they saw them as saber-rattling and not as a true political line.

I don't think those articles really support the idea that the west thinks Gorbachev and Yeltsin were "heroes", and in fact paints a more complicated picture of their relationship.
Gorbachev's article only mentions the word "hero" once, and it's applied to Stalin.
"Hero" is mentioned 5 times in Yeltsin's article, and not once is it unambiguously "the west". Once it was the opposite: the west "no longer" considered him a democratic hero (which implies he once was), twice specifically is it applied to Russians, and once in the general.
I don't think Yeltsin and Gorbachev are "so loved", whatever that really means, but the friendlier picture of them compared to their predecessors is obvious: they also were friendly with the west.
With Gorbachev, of course, begun the era of glasnost, which extended to friendlier (than before) relations with the west. He is seen as a stepping stone to democracy.
Yeltsin was the first leader of democratic Russia and had friendly relations with western leaders.
In this sense, it's not that the west was enamored with these two or thought them heroes, but applauded their stepping up to democratic reforms that unfrosted relations with the US and other western nations. It signaled the end of the Cold War, and as their figureheads, became associated with that end.

Well I like yeltsin drunk and dancing videos. He's really hilarious

@Huiying Beside the comic value, the most prominent of these videos is politically important (0:11 of your link): it shows him at the ceremony that concluded the withdrawal of the half-million strong contingent of the Red Army from East Germany.
